# Is there any way to stop the Trail Rotation with Player move?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Actually I'm making a space shooter type game. In which I'm adding trail to my player plane for this I'm using Trail Renderer

[image]

this is the screenshot of my inspector. Now the problem I'm facing is as and when I rotate my player plane trail also rotate and I don't want that to happen since the player rotate the trail should be straight only. Like this

Actual Problem : [image]

Expected Result : [image]

How can I fix this Rotation issue of Trail while I rotate my player. Do i need to code for this or what I'm not getting how do I solve this problem. I also tried to change the Alignment from 'View' to 'Transform Z' from inspector but its not solving the issue even I tried to change the Motion Vector but this also not giving proper result how I want. Please help me what can I do to resolve this issue. Thank You in advance.

Comment: Possibly make the 2 trail renderes their own gameObjects that follow 2 different transforms that are children of the airplane.

Comment: @Eddge can you please elaborate more I'm not getting what you want to say

Comment: I will write an answer with examples.  Warning my airplane wont be nearly as nice as your's though since I will just be combining cubes and cylinders/capsules to make it...

Comment: @Eddge No worry I just need the solution.

Comment: I just realized you dont want the rotation effect at all, so disregard what I said above as that will still give you a rotation effect(I thought you meant the trail renderer was rotating and creating weird results), you should create a particle system, set it to local in simulation space, and just set the velocity on the correct axis...  this will make it so it will always appear behind regardless of its rotation.  Also keep in mind realistically trails don't remain straight when a plane rotates.

Comment: hey @Eddge thank you, use of particle system was great idea its working for me now as per my requirement ...and yes thank you I'll keep in mind.